# Room database is returning 1 extra object

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have a room DB class that creates 3 user objects -

```java
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class UserDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

  private static UserDatabase instance;

  public abstract UserDao userDao();

  public static synchronized UserDatabase getInstance(Context context) {

    Log.d("inside observe - ", "inside database");

    if (instance == null) {
      instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), UserDatabase.class, "user_database").fallbackToDestructiveMigration().addCallback(roomUserCallback).build();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomUserCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
      super.onCreate(db);
      new PopulateDbAsyncTask(instance).execute();
    }
  };

  //TODO - delete this in the future. This is just for populating.
  private static class PopulateDbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    static final String URL = "https://www.shortlist.com/media/images/2019/05/40-favourite-songs-of-famous-people-28-1556672663-9rFo-column-width-inline.jpg";
    static final String URL2 = "https://img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net/tenant/amp/entityid/BBR9VUw.img?h=416&amp;w=624&amp;m=6&amp;q=60&amp;u=t&amp;o=f&amp;l=f&amp;x=2232&amp;y=979";
    static final String URL3 = "https://dz9yg0snnohlc.cloudfront.net/new-what-famous-people-with-depression-have-said-about-the-condition-1.jpg";
    private UserDao userDao;

    private PopulateDbAsyncTask(UserDatabase db) {
      userDao = db.userDao();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
      userDao.insert(new User(URL, "Barak Obama1", "/@BarakObama1"));
      userDao.insert(new User(URL2, "Barak Obama2", "/@BarakObama2"));
      userDao.insert(new User(URL3, "Barak Obama3", "/@BarakObama3"));
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

I am using viewmodel in order to fetch the users as LiveData. 
For some reason, at the first time I install my app, I get one extra "barak obama1" user created, and immedeatly after than all 3 "normal" users by order - barak obama3, 2 and 1. 
Here is my MainActivity -

```java
private ArrayList<User> usersList;
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fetchUserList();
  }

  private void fetchUserList() {
    userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
    final Observer<List<User>> userObserver = users -> {
      Log.d("inside observe - ", "inside main activity, list size - " + users.size());
      usersList = (ArrayList) users;
      initViewsAndListeners();
      addCards();
    };
    userViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, userObserver);
  }

  private void addCards(){
    TinderCardView tinderCardView;
    for (int i = 0; i < usersList.size(); i++) {
      tinderCardView = new TinderCardView(this);
      tinderCardView.bind(usersList.get(i));
      Log.d("inside observe - ", "inside main activity, user value - " + usersList.get(i).getUsername());
      tinderStackLayout.addCard(tinderCardView);
      Log.d("addCardCalled - ", "\nindex value - " + i + "\n" +
          "userlist size - " + usersList.size());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    int buttonTag = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(view.getTag()));
    TinderCardView topCardOnStack = tinderStackLayout.getTopCardOnStack();
    topCardOnStack.handleButtonPressed(buttonTag);
//    if (buttonTag == 1) { // TODO - move logic to card class
//       userViewModel.delete(usersList.get(0));
//       //fetchUserList();
//    }
  }

  private void initViewsAndListeners() {
    tinderStackLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_tinder_stack_layout);
    mDeleteButton = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_delete_button);
    mPassButton = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_pass_button);
    mApproveButton = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_approve_button);
    mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mApproveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mPassButton.setOnClickListener(this);
  }
```

As you can see I have log messages all over so you can understand what I am about to show you now. I am getting one extra user, "barak obama1" user first and then after that all other 3 -

[image]

The livedata figures out that there was 1 user in the list, adds in as a card and than the DB creates new objects and the livedata recalls the method, adding 3 more users.

Why is this happening?? I would glady kiss someone's leg if he solves this issue, no joke.

edit -

here is my ViewModel -

```java
public class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

  private UserRepository repository;
  private LiveData<List<User>> allUsers;

  public UserViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    repository = new UserRepository(application);
    allUsers = repository.getAllUsers();

  }

  public void insert(User user) {
    repository.insert(user);
  }

  public void update(User user) {
    repository.update(user);
  }

  public void delete(User user) {
    repository.delete(user);
  }

  public void deleteAllUsers(){
    repository.deleteAllUsers();
  }

  public LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers() {
    Log.d("inside observe - ", "inside viewmodel");
    return allUsers;
  }
}
```

and my respository -

```java
public class UserRepository {

  private UserDao userDao;
  private LiveData<List<User>> allUsers;

  public UserRepository(Application application) {
    UserDatabase database = UserDatabase.getInstance(application);
    userDao = database.userDao();
    allUsers = userDao.getAllUsers();
  }

  public void insert(User user) {
    new InsertUserAsyncTask(userDao).execute(user);
  }

  public void update(User user) {
    new UpdateUserAsyncTask(userDao).execute(user);
  }

  public void delete(User user) {
    new DeleteUserAsyncTask(userDao).execute(user);
  }

  public void deleteAllUsers() {
    new DeleteAllUsersAsyncTask();
  }

  public LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers() {
    Log.d("inside observe - ", "inside repository");
    return allUsers;
  }

  //TODO - migrate all 4 async tasks into one.
  private static class InsertUserAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<User, Void, Void> {

    private UserDao userDao;

    private InsertUserAsyncTask(UserDao userDao) {
      this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(User... users) {
      userDao.insert(users[0]);
      return null;
    }
  }

  private static class UpdateUserAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<User, Void, Void> {

    private UserDao userDao;

    private UpdateUserAsyncTask(UserDao userDao) {
      this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(User... users) {
      userDao.update(users[0]);
      return null;
    }
  }

  private static class DeleteUserAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<User, Void, Void> {

    private UserDao userDao;

    private DeleteUserAsyncTask(UserDao userDao) {
      this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(User... users) {
      userDao.delete(users[0]);
      return null;
    }
  }

  private static class DeleteAllUsersAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private UserDao userDao;

    private DeleteAllUsersAsyncTask() {
      this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
      userDao.deleteAllUsers();
      return null;
    }
  }


}
```

edit -

here is my dao -

```java
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

  @Insert
  void insert(User user);

  @Update
  void update(User user);

  @Delete
  void delete(User user);

  @Query("DELETE FROM user_table")
  void deleteAllUsers();

  @Query("SELECT * FROM user_table ORDER BY id DESC")
  LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers();




}
```

Comment: thats how live data works. its not returning anything extra. it is returning what you have asked it to return. so when you render data check whether you have already rendered the data if not then render it. simple !!!

Comment: you mean, in the database class I should check if I have already uploaded the data? and if yes - can you please tell me what would be the correct way to do so according to my database class that I provided?

Comment: What is your `ViewModel` looks like?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman edited and added both viewmodel and respository

Comment: Try to add `tinderStackLayout.removeAllViews()` at first line of `addCards()` and check. Its not a problem of liveData. I will explain later, first check whether its work or not.

Comment: @AlonShlider, Did you try my solution?

Comment: just tried it now with the solution of roi bareket and it works like I want but I am confused which one is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert all users in 1 transaction.
2 approaches: 
1. Create a function in dao that receive list of users.
2. Create a transaction in roomDB (google how. Very simple)

I prefer the first one

Comment: your solution seems correct but I did not find anything at google about this and my self implelemntation did not work correctly. could you please link to me a google search/edit and post a code example?

Comment: ` abstract class UsersDao{ @Insert abstract fun insertUsers(users: List<User>) : Long @Transaction open fun deleteAndInsertUsersAsTransaction(users: List<User>) { deleteAllUsers() // db call 1 insertUsers(users) // db call 2 } }`

Answer (score 1):

try to understand
i have made comments

this is raw code just to give you idea

```
private ArrayList<User> usersList;

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.usersList = new ArrayList(); // initalise the array list here
    fetchUserList();
  }

  private void fetchUserList() {
    userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
    final Observer<List<User>> userObserver = users -> {
      Log.d("inside observe - ", "inside main activity, list size - " + users.size());
      usersList = (ArrayList) users; //dont do this ! instead follow the below instructions
      // to do
      for(User user : users){
        if(!usersList.contains(user)){
            usersList.add(user);
        }
      }
      // to do ends here
      initViewsAndListeners();
      addCards();
    };
    userViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, userObserver);
  }

}
```

look what i have done:

- initalised the usersList
- and when observing the users live data i use loop and in that loop i
  check if this user is already added

do you get it ?

Comment: Thank you I will try your solution. I just don't understand why would there be any duplicate information at the first place! How can that be, the app has just been installed.

Comment: its because, when u do this 'usersList = (ArrayList) users;' in your observer. the observer gets the data 2 times and your code just takes the data and renders it so as many times data comes it renders. what i have done i have initalised the userArrayList in oncreate and in observer i check if the data has already been rendered ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the database starts to create 3 objects, when finishing the first one a livedata is being sent upwards, giving me only one object out of 3 (because data has been changed), so I am getting one object one time and the second time getting all the 3. If what I am saying is correct, why wouldn't I get 1 object, then 2 objects and than 3 objects?

Comment: added dao in first comment